# python for loop create a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Ok guys,
Why does this simple for-loop fail to fill a list?
Here is what I have:

```
axx = []
for i in range(1,7):
  axx.append('ax'+str(i))
  print(axx[i])
```

I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin_data2.py", line 57, in <module>
    print(axx[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This should pretty simple and straightforward, isn't it?
Sorry, coming from Fortran background!

Answer (score 5):

You need `i-1` while printing. Array is appended starting from `0` and `i` starts from `1`. So, at first `append`, there is element at `0` but `i` has value of `1`:

```
print(axx[i-1])
```

If you look into result from:

```
print(list(range(1,7)))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Or, you may change the range to `range(6)` instead of `range(1,7)`. However, it will print with value of `0`. In that case, you want `axx.append('ax'+str(i+1))`

Comment: Still doesn't work. It shouldn't matter as I am not accessing the `axx[0]`. Something is wrong with the for-loop and list assignment.

Comment: For above code, it did give result fine. When you are calling `print` first time then i has value of 1, but the list only has element at 0 so, it is out of index.

Comment: Alternatively, stop bothering with `i` when printing; `axx[-1]` will always show the final item in the `list`, and since you append on the previous line, it's always the value you just appended.

Comment: So in this case, `for i in range(1,7): axx.append('ax'+str(i))` is somewhat redundant, as python will always start the array index from 0. So, as far as I can understand `for i in range(1,7)` should be replaced by `for i in range(1,7)` .

Comment: I think what you meant is replace `for i in range(1,7)` with `for i in range(6)` then, it will start from 0 till 5 i.e. less than last element. And in your `append`, you may want as `str(i+1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Never mind. It seems you can't have a list `[ax1,ax2,ax3..]` without the index of `ax1` being 0. I guess that's how python works. You will have `[ax1,ax2,ax3..]` but have to keep in mind that ax1 is actually the zero-th element, which is a bit confusing when you try to access it.

Comment: As far as I know, that's how indexing of array is on other languages such as `C`, `C++`, `Java` as well. Arrays in `R` has starting from `1`, I think

Comment: @student There are [a few others too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array)#Array_dimensions): the better-known ones include Lua, MATLAB/Octave/Julia, and Smalltalk. The vast majority of languages have zero-indexed arrays, though.

Comment: @JackTaylor Thanks! I did not know much about other languages :)

Answer (score 3):

Lists are indexed from zero. Your loop loops over `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, or six times. Your list `axx` will end up a list with length six, indexes zero to five (`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4. 5]`). But you access it as `i`, which is one greater than the current index. So you will need to subtract one from it to get the value at the right position.

So don't use `range(1,7)`, use `range(6)`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget python uses zero-based indexing. Your range (1,7) is going from 1 to 6, but your list has an item at place 0 after the first loop, so your print statement is always one i behind. Change range function to be range(7), or change print function to be print(i).

```
axx = []
for i in range(7):
    axx.append('ax'+str(i))
    print(axx[i])
```

output:
ax0
ax1
ax2
ax3
ax4
ax5
ax6

OR

```
axx = []
for i in range(1,7):
    axx.append('ax'+str(i))
    print(i)
```

output:
1
2
3
4
5
6

If you don't want your list to include ax0, try:

```
axx = []
for i in range(7):
    axx.append('ax'+str(i+1))
    print(axx[i])
```

output:
ax1
ax2
ax3
ax4
ax5
ax6
ax7

Also consider next time printing the whole list after it was been populated, so you know what your code is doing. This is the same code you had originally, just without printing i each time you append.

```
axx = []
for i in range(1,7):
    axx.append('ax'+str(i))

print(axx)
```

output:
['ax1', 'ax2', 'ax3', 'ax4', 'ax5', 'ax6']